# MongoTemplate Vs MongoRepository for specific use cases

Tags: java, mongodb, mongotemplate, mongorepository

I am building my web app using mongodb and one of the list apis requires pagination. On reading about the ways to implement pagination in mongodb, I figured out that it can be implemented only using MongoRepository like below

```
Sort sort = Sort.by(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "created_time"));
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size, sort);
        Page<Model> page = repository.findAll(pageable);
```

As far as my understanding goes, there is no way we can paginate using MongoTemplate without fetching all the data.

Also my usecase involves making complex searches and I see that MongoTemplate offers better granular control.

How can I make the best out of both the mongo dao layers ?